# Can I include forecasted values as explanatory variables when forecasting?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am wondering about a problem I have encountered. If I were to use income as an explanatory variable in an ARIMA model to forecast  consumption, I would need future values for income to include in the forecast of the consumption. Would it be a problem if I used another forecast of consumption as an explanatory variable when forecasting the future income that I would then include in the forecast of consumption itself? Stepwise to be a little more clear:

1. Forecast consumption-prices using OLS/ETS/ARIMA
2. Create model for income including consumption as an explanatory variable
3. Forecasting the income using the forecast of consumption as values for the xreg-argument in the forecast function (Using a forecast of consumption when forecasting income)
4. Create a model for consumption with income as an explanatory variable
5. Forecast consumption using the forecast of income as the value for the xreg-argument in the forecast function. (Using the forecast of income when forecasting consumption)

Is there any theoretical problem doing this? First forecast income on consumption and then forecast consumption on income?

I appriciate the help guys!

Comment: Which are you forecasting first? Future consumption or future income?

Comment: @Henry I am forecasting future consumption first, and my final goal is also to forecast future consumption consumption!